# How to split an arbitrary math expression by its multipliers

Tags: python, string, split, symbolic-math

I want to split long math equation by multipliers. 
The expression is given as a string where whitespaces are allowed.

For example:

```
"((a*b>0) * (e>500)) * (abs(j)>2.0) * (n>1)"
```

Should return:

```
['a*b>0', 'e>500', 'abs(j)>2.0', 'n>1']
```

If the division is used things get even more complicated, but let assume there is no division for the start. What would be the most pythonic way to solve this?

Comment: Is every part isolated with brackets?

Comment: What have you done since now? You faced any particular issue?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, no, but in case input string would be "(a*b)>c*d" output should be ['(a*b)>c*d'] or ['a*b>c*d']

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

string = "((a-b>0) * (e + 10>500)) * (abs(j)>2.0) * (n>1)"
signals = {'+','*','/','-'}

###
##

def splitString(string):

    arr_equations = re.split(''([\)]+(\*|\-|\+|\/)+[\(])'',string.replace(" ", ""))

    new_array = []

    for each_equa in arr_equations:

        each_equa = each_equa.strip("()")

        if (not(each_equa in signals)):
            new_array.append(each_equa)

    return new_array

###
##    

print(splitString(string))
```

Comment: `((a*b>c)-(a*b>c))` this example will produce ['a*b>c', 'a*b>c']

Comment: @greyxray when i run my programme, that example works fine, check it again.                                                                                                    
        Output:  `['a*b>c', 'a*b>c']`

Comment: but that is not splitting by multipliers, it's subtraction operation

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `split()` function:

```
ans_list = your_string.split(" * ")
```

Note the spaces around the multiplier sign. This assumes that your string is exactly as you say.

Comment: This will split the inner multiplier as well: `['((a', 'b>0) ', ' (e>500)) ', ' (abs(j)>2.0) ', ' (n>1)']`.

Comment: Fixed, atleast for the example OP gave

Comment: @pCube You are assuming that there are no spaces wrapping the inner multiplier...

Comment: @pCube: to be honest, I do not think this really solves the issue. Based on the question, a user can probably enter an arbitrary expression. So he/she can enter `(a * b)*c`. Which will split the inner and not split the outer one.

Comment: Agree with the too many assumptions part. But this works for OP's example. I can try to come up with a more general solution if need be.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think there will need to be some arbitrary split requirements, currently the OPs expression is split at multiple levels in the parse tree, space separated operator seems as arbitrary as bracketed expressions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex:

```
s = "((a*b>0) * (e>500)) * (abs(j)>2.0) * (n>1)"
s = ''.join(s.split())
s = re.split(r'([\)]+[\*\+\-/\^]+[\(])', s)
res = []
for x in s:
    x = re.sub(r'(^[\(\)\*\+\-\/]+)', '', x)
    x = re.sub(r'([\(\)]+$)', '', x)
    if len(x) > 0: res.append(x)
print(res)
```

Comment: Regex answers are more helpful if you explain how the regex works.

Comment: First, I splited s by '[)]+*[(]+',  then I removed some '(' at start or ')' at end of string

Comment: @nguyenthanhchinh, contrexample `"((a*b>c) - (a*b>c))"` will produce `['a*b>c)-(a*b>c']`

Comment: @greyxrar, I just fixed the answer, hope it helps

Comment: @nguyenthanhchinh You should edit your answer to include the explanation instead of leaving it in the comments.